# select highest sale with date from sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select max(total), date
from (select sum(total) as total, date as date
      from canteen
      group by date) as max
```

i want to select the highest sale and the date of the highest sale from table.

With my query this error is shown.

> Exception, Error code 8,120, SQLState S0001] Column 'max.date' is
>   invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use order by, set your data to order by sale descending and fetch first row.

If you wants result by date then you can use ROW_NUMBER()

```
select TOP(1) total, date
from 
(
  select sum(total) as total, date as date
  from canteen
  group by date
) as max
Order by todal desc
```

Comment: thanks a lot . it worked . if it's not too much trouble can u tell me what is wrong with my query

Comment: @Mohit: you have forgotten to add group by & order by to your outer query.

Comment: @Mohit: you have used select max(total) in outer query which miss group by in statement

Answer (score 0):

This will return all dates achieving the max sales total. [Here](http://rextester.com/NICBD87221) is a demo.

```
; with x as (
    select sum(total) as total, date from canteen group by date
)
, y as (
    select dr = dense_rank() over(order by total desc), *
    from x
)
select * from y where dr = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all dates with max(total), here it is

```
;with temp as 
(
   select sum(total) as total, date as date
   from canteen
   group by date
)
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM temp 
ORDER BY temp.total desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to add group by & order by in your outer query. I have modified it to display all the sales in descending order. So the highest sale will be at top.

```
select max(total) total, date
from (select sum(total) as total, date as date
      from canteen
      group by date) as max
group by date 
order by total desc
```